# how to zip two files using 7zip via command line option

Tags: command-line, 7zip

how to zip two files using 7zip via command line option. i want zip both files versioninfo.ini  and Summary.xml with name Local.zip

exmple

7za a -t7z Local.7z versioninfo.ini Summary.xml (not working)

Comment: The syntax is correct. What's the error message?

Comment: for a full run down of all the commands available type `7z --help` in to a Terminal window. Perhaps if you replace `7za` with `7z` it may work.

Answer (score 1):

To install 7z archiver as a command line utility, You need to install the p7zip-full package.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

After both p7zip and p7zip-full are installed, you will see the following three command line utilities installed in your Linux box :

```
7z uses plugins to handle archives.
7za is a stand-alone executable. 7za handles fewer archive formats than 7z, but does not need any others.
7zr is a stand-alone executable. 7zr handles fewer archive formats than 7z, but does not need any others. 7zr is a "light-version" of 7za that only handles 7z archives.
```

<sup>Source IBM</sup>